# Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up -why?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new in this field and I would like to ask how can i loop if I am trying to achieve this scenario: (JAVA CODE THAT INVOLVES SELENIUM AND WEBDRIVER)

- I am on a listview for example Account module. Then in the account module IF there is a pagination(button for Click for more accounts) THEN I will click it, WHEN there is no more pagination seen in the listview then I will execute a blocks of Code.
- If there is no pagination in the listview then I will automatically execute a blocks of code.

Here is the block of codes i want to execute if the "Click for more accounts" is not anymore present in the listview

```
    List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button"));
    for(WebElement click:button){
        while(click.isDisplayed()){

            WebDriverWait JEAN11 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
            JEAN11.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button")));
            click.click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);

        }
        WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
        System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());

    }
```

Why am I receiving  `Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up` :(

Comment: You're looking for `while`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Your condition will be : `if(list.size()>0) then ...//do action`

Comment: Still im getting : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: What you want to check exactly? do you want like if pagination is there then process forward otherwise stop ??

Comment: What i want to check is that if the button is present in the listview, i want it to be clicked and I want it to loop around until it doesnt see the button anymore if there is no button to be click on the first load - proceed on the last statement i have in the description. And if the button is not present in the listview ON THE FIRST LOAD proceed with the last 3statements i have on the description. @HelpingHands

Comment: I see.. First of all according to your given error in last comment , you will have to use explicit wait till that button gets visible because here situation is that button getting time to load and when web driver checks at that time yet button is not loaded so you are getting that error. Second thing is according to your last comment you will have to use 2 conditions , first is for `if(list.size()>0)` then if button visible then use `while(list.length)`

Comment: I now get : 
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up @HelpingHands

Comment: @HelpingHands, I edited my description please see above code and let me know what you think on this. Im really having a hard time about that error.

Comment: @JeanLumen - that error mostly comes when webdriver try to find element and element till not loaded on page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82555/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-jean-lumen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to

1 - separate check "Click for more accounts" and "Total Number of TR:"

2 - spy new objects in this case. (Do not spy object just 1 time, then use it for your rest of script like you did)

So the code should be

```
while(clickMore == true) {
    List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button"));
    if(button.size() > 0) {
        button.get(0).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
    else clickMore = false;
}

WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
```

Comment: Hi @Nguyen , 
how do I initialize the clickMore you have specified ? should i have i put `boolean clickMORE = false` ??