# How do I loop on a button that if it is present then click if not then proceed with the code

Tags: java, selenium

I am new in this field and I would like to ask how can i loop if I am trying to achieve this scenario: (JAVA CODE THAT INVOLVES SELENIUM AND WEBDRIVER)

- I am on a listview for example Account module. Then in the account module IF there is a pagination(button for Click for more accounts) THEN I will click it, WHEN there is no more pagination seen in the listview then I will execute a blocks of Code.
- If there is no pagination in the listview then I will automatically execute a blocks of code.

Here is my code:

```
    WebElement more = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]"));
    List<WebElement> button = more.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button"));
    for(WebElement clicks:button){
        for(int i=0; i!=100 ;i++){
            if(clicks.isEnabled()){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button")).click();
            }else{
                WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
                List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
                System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
            }
            WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
            List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
            System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
        }


    }
```

When I run it I have this error Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: This is a nearly exact duplicate of your last question: [How to loop on an IF condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258018/how-to-loop-on-an-if-condition).

Comment: In your code there is no need of else block. Just remove it and try to execute your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-catch structure to check if the pagination element is present (and catch the error if the element is not present).
If the element is not present, then an error will be given so execution will never reach the contents of the else block. Thus, everything in the else block should be in a catch block, which will be executed if the pagination element is not present.